# Is there an easy way to generate documentation for eclipse without disturbing the code?

Tags: java, eclipse, documentation

I have to produce a report on all of my program's classes and methods and put it into a word document. Now, I really want to know if there is a software that will generate a text file documentation from my project files without inserting comments to source codes. I just want a list of all methods and classes in a text or ms word file, so that I can fill in the description on my own.

Comment: Can't you just generate Javadoc HTML artifacts?

Comment: I need it in a word document, so that I can print hard copy and turn it in to the professor.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* generate javadoc documentation just from uncommented source code. It will generate HTML, but there are probably converters to Word available.

However, I would *strongly* recommend that you add comments to your code instead. It's what Java programmers the world over expect; the documentation will show up in tooltips when you're writing new code calling into your current API; the tooling is geared up for it. Basically, try to work *with* the language conventions instead of fighting them.

EDIT: It sounds like you can use a `doclet` to generate the Word document for you. The [MIF Doclet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/mifdoclet/5/docs/mifdoclet.html) may be a good starting point, or [PDFDoclet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfdoclet/).

Answer (score 1):

Generate the documentation using javadoc and then convert it to the required format. Look for different options here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javadoc-faq.html#print.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Maven plugin, "[maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/)" that is useful for producing editable HTML docs from a Java project.